# Why Tsunade-sama did not have wood element even though she was direct descendant of Senju Hashirama-sama?

Tags: naruto

Most of the time in *Naruto* I have seen that the descendants of a particular clan will inherit the elements from their clan.

For example, Uchiha clans mostly have fire element in them.

But why didn't Tsunade-sama inherit the wood element from her grandfather?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hashirama's Wood element is, as far as the series goes, completely unique to him. It was not inherited to his descendants, and even his own brother didn't have it.

There were only a few exceptions:

1. Yamato, who is the sole survivor from an experiment to inject Hashirama's DNA into babies.
2. Danzo, who injected himself with Hashirama's cells to be able to use Izanagi, but was too unstable to actually use it.
3. Madara, who injected himself with Hashirama's cells after acquiring them from their battle.
4. Zetsu, who has been born of the Shinju's power.
5. Obito (while wearing Zetsu).

Madara is the only other person capable of using the actual Wood element large scale techniques like Jukai Kotan and Kajukai Korin.

Comment: Anywhere is it said that why this has happened? I mean why wood element have not been inherited by his successors?

Comment: None that I can remember. My guess is that Wood element was just too OP  to pass around toe less important characters.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I agree but to be passed down to Hashirama, Shouldn't there be someone in the senju clan who was very advanced and used the wood style Or maybe Hashirama was the first in his clan. Its same as the rinnegan. Not every Uchiha can use it. It's a possession of the advanced ninjas. So if Tsunade trained hard enough, can she at some point in time use wood style?

Comment: @Madara'sGhost Obito already had Hashirama cells injected in him before he had Zetsu attached. Although you are correct that he gained more after Zetsu's attachment.

Comment: @VarunRao Hashirama has Wood-Style due to being Ashura's reincarnate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason Tsunade or any Senju descendants weren't able to use wood style is likely related to their life-force and physical energy.

Hashirama was a reincarnation of Asura, therefore his physical energy and life-force were more powerful than other descendants of Asura, the same way Madara's ocular powers were more powerful than other Uchiha's because of him being a reincarnation of Indra.

Asura used Sage Art Wood Release: True Several Thousand Hands jutsu to battle against Indra's Susanoo.